# C switch statement and enum explicit cast

Tags: c, enums, casting, switch-statement, gobject

Saw a lot of similar questions but none answer my question here:
Suppose I have an enum `Property`:

```c
enum
{
    PROP_A = 1,
    PROP_B,
    N_PROPERTIES
} Property;
```

When I try to use it in a switch statement like this:

```c
// file test.c
enum
{
    PROP_A = 1,
    PROP_B,
    N_PROPERTIES
} Property;

int main(void)
{
    int a = 0;
    switch ((Property) a)
    {
        case PROP_A:
            break;
        case PROP_B:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    };
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler throws this error:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:11:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘a’
   11 |  switch ((Property) a)
      |         ~          ^~
      |                    )
```

What is wrong with this code? For reference, in the GObject documentation they have this snippet:

```c
typedef enum
{
  PROP_FILENAME = 1,
  PROP_ZOOM_LEVEL,
  N_PROPERTIES
} ViewerFileProperty;

static GParamSpec *obj_properties[N_PROPERTIES] = { NULL, };

static void
viewer_file_set_property (GObject      *object,
                          guint         property_id,
                          const GValue *value,
                          GParamSpec   *pspec)
{
  ViewerFile *self = VIEWER_FILE (object);

  switch ((ViewerFileProperty) property_id)
    {
    case PROP_FILENAME:
      g_free (self->filename);
      self->filename = g_value_dup_string (value);
      g_print ("filename: %s\n", self->filename);
      break;

    case PROP_ZOOM_LEVEL:
      self->zoom_level = g_value_get_uint (value);
      g_print ("zoom level: %u\n", self->zoom_level);
      break;

    default:
      /* We don't have any other property... */
      G_OBJECT_WARN_INVALID_PROPERTY_ID (object, property_id, pspec);
      break;
    }
}
```

Which is essentially the same thing. Therefore it must be possible. What's wrong with my version?

Comment: Property is the identifier of an enum object of anonymous type, not the identifier of an enum type...

Comment: @DevSolar Thank you! can't believe I didn't see that. So casting is only possible if you typedef an enum! Gotcha!

Comment: Also, minor nitpick: a semicolon is not necessary after the closing brace of a `switch`.

Comment: Casts involve a type name. In your example, `Property` is a variable, rather than a type name.

Comment: You could also just *name* the enum type properly. Typedefs are optional, and personally I don't like them unless the type is opaque (e.g. `FILE`). They tend to hide some rather crucial information, like what a type actually *is*...

Comment: "So casting is only possible if you typedef an enum"...well, sort of. You cast to a type, not an instance of that type (which is what DevSolar was getting at).

Comment: Taking enums out of the equation for a second, it's as if you wrote: `int a = 4; int b; switch ((b) a) { ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this declaration

```
    enum
    {
        PROP_A = 1,
        PROP_B,
        N_PROPERTIES
    } Property;
```

you declared an object `Property` of an unnamed enumeration type.

So in the switch statement

```
switch ((Property) a)
```

you are using a syntactically incorrect expressions with two objects `Property` and `a`.

It seems you mean

```
    typedef enum
    {
        PROP_A = 1,
        PROP_B,
        N_PROPERTIES
    } Property;
```

Pay attention that you may just write

```
switch ( a )
```

In C enumerators have the type `int`. That is these enumerators PROP_A,             PROP_B, N_PROPERTIES all have the type `int`. So the casting that you tried to apply (if the enumeration would be declared correctly) is redundant.

Comment: Re “So the casting that you tried to apply (if the enumeration would be declared correctly) is redundant”: The enumeration constants have type `int`, but the enumeration type is compatible with some implementation-defined non-enumeration integer type that can represent all the values of the enumeration. Then the cast can affect the value. For example, when `Property` is compatible with 8-bit `unsigned char`, as it is in Apple Clang 11 with `-fshort-enums`, and `a` has been set to −255, then the switch with the `cast` branches to `case PROP_A:`, but the switch without it branches to `default:`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil So the casting is redundant because enumerators have the type int. Otherwise you can get an unexpected result as you described.

Answer (score 3):

> Suppose I have an enum Property:
>
> ```
> enum
> {
>     PROP_A = 1,
>     PROP_B,
>     N_PROPERTIES
> } Property;
> ```

Your code does not define `Property` as an enum *type*.  It declares it as a *variable* whose type is an untagged enum type.  Typecast operators must be constructed from types, not variables, so `(Property) a` is invalid.

That cast is also *unnecessary*.  One way to solve the problem would be simply to drop it:

```
    switch (a) {
        case PROP_A:
            break;
        case PROP_B:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Alternatively, if you mean to define `Property` as a type alias, then that is the function of `typedef`:

```
typedef enum {
    PROP_A = 1,
    PROP_B,
    N_PROPERTIES
} Property;
```

Personally, however, I am not a fan of `typedef`.  It has a few good uses, but it tends to be applied far beyond those.  If I wanted to declare an enum type that I could reference apart from its declaration, then I would include a tag:

```
enum property {
    PROP_A = 1,
    PROP_B,
    N_PROPERTIES
};

int main(void) {
    int a = 0;
    switch ((enum property) a) {
        case PROP_A:
            break;
        case PROP_B:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(The cast is included for demonstrative purposes -- it's still unnecessary.)

Comment: Thank you. In your opinion, why did the devs of GObject use the typedef for their `Property` enum?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `typedef` before `enum` to identify `Property` as a type.  In the other example you provided for comparison, `typedef` is used.